# Cannot seem to delete an object number

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I seem to have a problem deleting order numbers in Django. In my views, there is an order number equals to some pk value. There is also a submit button which should delete this number in the template. Unfortunately it is doing nothing (not deleting).

For some reason I thought these changes would delete an object, but it's still not working.

Basically I have this.

```
order = models.Order.objects.get(pk=1219)
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    order.delete()
```

And in my template I have this.

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" >
```

Comment: why are you setting the order variable as a tuple?

Comment: @uku I thought by doing that way it could delete. The thing is my definition of orders is defined in another view. I can only use it by using sessions. see above.

Comment: @Shehzad009: "I thought by doing that way it could delete."  What?  Why?  Do you know how `delete` works in Django? "The thing is my definition of orders..." Means nothing.  Did you read this?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#delete

Comment: Did you check weather it executes if block, may be it do not even enter that block (one possible reason is method of the form).

Comment: @Shehzad009: Please post more code.  This is correct use of the API, therefore, something else is going wrong.

Comment: @fallenangel It does reach that block. It does something, but does not delete.

Comment: @Shehzad009: Please post more code.  "It does reach that block. It does something, but does not delete" is impossible to understand without more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. :) had

```
order = models.Order.objects.get(pk=1219)
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    order.delete()
```

in the wrong view! Can't believe I was this stupid.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line you are initializing `order` with a tuple.
In the fourth line you call `delete()` on that object.

I don't know, if that is what you intended. I cannot make any more sense out of what you wrote. Maybe you could give us some more detail.